# Full background image not displaying on mobile device

Tags: css

**The full background image isn't displaying properly on mobile. How can I have the full background image display?**

```
body {
background-color: #000; 
background-image: url(http://godwellontheloose.com/IMG_0463bwssww.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;       
webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
}   

a {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the HTML and body to be 100% height and width first.

```
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Once this is added any element set to 100% height will show it at 100% height. A working example is below, run the code and click on full screen.

```css
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;}
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.background{background-image:url('https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/85/48/e6/seven-mile-beach-grand.jpg');width:100%; height:100%;
background-color: #000; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;       
webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<div class="background"><a href="#test"></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - the full image doesn't appear on mobile still: godwellonthelooose.com

Comment: Which mobile are you trying on?